# Are .sparsebundle files _alive_?

Tags: backup, sparsebundle

Even if I don't do anything with the files in a .sparsebundle, just having a .sparsebundle open, it seems it is *alive*. Let me explain.

I regularly backup my main .sparsebundle (that sits on my Desktop) using *rsync*. I have an alias to do that, so every once in a while, I call that command to make sure everything is backed up properly to my external HDD. If I *rsync* multiple times in a row, at first, *rsync* updates many bands, then less, even less, and eventually it doesn't have anything to do anymore, all the bands are up-to-date. However, without using anything in the .sparsebundle on my Desktop, if I try to *rsync* again after e.g. 5 minutes, sometimes there are more bands to update! Why is that? Does the sparse bundle mechanism include, e.g. an OS background process that optimizes the bands silently?

Comment: Is the sparse bundle mounted while you're "not using it", or is it unmounted?

Comment: It is mounted - I just have it mounted and showing up on my desktop, but I am not using anything that's on it, as far as I can tell - no file, no application. Oh - and I have also asked Spotlight to not index it, so it's probably not Spotlight.